# Do I need a second Azure data storage to save files uploaded by users?

Tags: azure

I got two data storages in my Windows Azure account. One is for the web application itself, and I created a second one to store files uploaded by the end users.

My question is -is that second data storage actually needed? I created it because every time I deploy my web app, I get the message, "The selected deployment environment is in use, would you like to replace the current deployment?".
I infer from that message that, if I store uploaded files in the web app data storage, they will be replaced on every deployment.

So I am basically trying to confirm if my interpretation is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's telling you that the cloud service environment slot (production or staging) already has a service in it. It has NOTHING to do with the storage account. So no, I dn't elieve you need a second storage account unless you need it specifically for scaling purposes (exceeding the 5k transaction per second limit) or security (controlling access to data).

Comment: +1 for security and performance. Great idea to store diagnostics in separate storage account from app data.

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your Windows Azure application from Visual Studio, to a specific service name "xyz" in "production" or "staging" slot, if there is already an application deployed to same service name "xyz" and same "production" or "staging" slot, then you will get such message as "The selected deployment environment is in use, would you like to replace the current deployment?". This is because with Visual Studio the deployment to an existed slot will be redeployed after deleting the deployment.

In this whole situation the "Azure Blob Storage" is only used to place your Azure application package at "vsdeploy" named container.

So you sure can use on single "Windows Azure Storage" name for all of you application and that would be better design.